# Convergence in Probabiliy

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

$X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability and a sequence of constants $|c_n|$ diverges to infinity. Can someone please help me prove that $X_n - c_n$ does not converge to $0$.
(I am totally blank as to how I should combine the convergence in probability and divergence of a sequence of constants. I know the basic concepts and definitions, but don't know how to bring them together for the particular problem)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $X_n$ by $|X_n|$ and $c_n$ by $|c_n|$, it's is enough to prove the result when $c_n\to +\infty$ and $c_n$'s are real numbers. 
There is $n_0$ such that $c_n\gt 2$ for $n\geqslant n_0$
$$\mathbb P\{c_n-X_n\gt 1\}=\mathbb P\{X_n<c_n-1\}\geqslant \mathbb P\{X_n\lt 1\}=1-\mathbb P\{X_n\geqslant 1\}.$$

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Actually, the result holds if $c_n$ doesn't not converge to $0$.